# How to extract specific tags from XML file using Perl

Tags: xml, perl, unix

I have a XML file.
I want to extract the elements between the following tags- article-id, title,p 
I want to know how to extract the elements stored in between these tags and save to a csv file.

XML file-

```
<artile-id>1234</article-id>
<title>A</title>
<p>Hi</p>
<title>B</title>
<p>contents</p>
<title>C</title>
<p>Hello</p>
```

I only want to extract the elements between title tags when only 'A' or 'C' is present and the contents stored under the title between p tags.

Desired output- 1234,A,Hi,C,Hello

I want to know how to search and match the elements of title tag also include the elements stored between p tags using Perl

Comment: not clear for which programming language you want the solution

Comment: What a stupid format. Anyway, you want something like [this](https://pastebin.com/a0EBAbr7).

Comment: @AnkurJyotiPhukan, that portion is perfectly clear to me, because the heading specifically says "How to extract specific tags from XML file using Perl"

Comment: @SAM1 please review the edits and approve and the thread can be taken off the hold status, then we can answer.

Comment: @User5422332 I have tried editing the post now. Please tell me if it makes sense now

Comment: I have just been able to extract title elements using the following perl code-                                                                                                       perl -lne 'BEGIN{undef $/} while (/<title>(.*?)<\/title>/sg){print $1}' sample.xml . Can you tell me how to obtain other elements from all the tags. I don't have much knowledge about this. @User5422332